# Delete files from a specific folder in C

Tags: c, file-io, directory, cygwin, opendir

I'm trying to delete files from a specifc folder. My `deleteFile()` function only deletes on its home folder, not on `/tmp` folder which is what I need. I tried the same approach as my `displayDIR()` function to change directory but I can't figure out how to make it work. I use cygwin as compiler.

```
void deleteFile() {
    int status;
    char filetodelete[25];

    printf("\n \t **Delete File**\n");

    displayDIR();

    printf("\n\tChoose the name of the file to delete:\t");
    scanf("%s", filetodelete);

    status = remove(filetodelete);
    if( status == 0 )
        printf("%s file deleted successfully.\n",  filetodelete);
    else {
        printf("\n\tUnable to delete the file");
        perror("\n\tError");
    }
}


void displayDIR() {
    DIR           *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    d = opendir("C:/cygwin/tmp");
    if (d) {
        while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
             printf("\t\t\t%s\n", dir->d_name);

        closedir(d);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot call `printf` before calling `perror`, since the call to `printf` may modify `errno` and change the message that would otherwise be written by `perror`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the folder path in the argument to `remove()`:

```
char fullpath[40] = "C:/cygwin/tmp/";
strcat(fullpath, filetodelete);
status = remove(fullpath);
```

Comment: Oh right! It's path. Why didn't it crossed my mind. Why am I directly changing the directory directly on the program haha. Thanks dude.