# Can't remove text file if it is at different locations except it's root directory

Tags: c

I can't remove the file if it is in another location except it's root directory

```
if (remove("C:\\\abcd.txt") == -1)
```

Its not working

Comment: What is errno after it fails? That will tell you why it did not work...

Comment: Error is no such file or directory

Comment: But the file exist at the directory

Comment: Then no, the file doesn't exist.
Maybe you have hidden extension, and the file is "C:\\abcd.txt.txt", check it.

Comment: Are you sure that is the *exact* line of code you are using?  The `If` is wrong for a start.  Make sure you are using double back slashes as you show, or use a forward slash (which is valid from C on Windows).  Also double check the filename.  As @Tom's said, default settings on Windows Explorer omits the file extension, safer to check using `cmd.exe` `dir` command.

Comment: OK I checked the file name,  is correct, but it I am only Able to delete the files which are present in its root directory... Please tell me how to listen the whole HDD

Comment: could you please update your question with the whole code, not just a partial one, and with printing why the function have failed (using errno, perror, strerror, ...) and with error message. At this rate, it's more a game of "guess who it is ?" than a debugging.

Comment: @tom I am using perror

Comment: It is only deleting files which are present under the folders having only single word name (like folder abc)

Comment: Can you please do as Tom has instructed before carrying on spitting out shady explanations ? Thanks.

Comment: Please check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22003626/6448640)

Comment: Voting to close as "Unclear" since the example is badly formatted which may or may not be part of the problem, a full explanation missing, and the description and title are contradiciting – the example file *is* in the root directory and yet you say it cannot be deleted because "its not working".

Comment: 1. Please show the __exact__ code that works and the __exact__ code that doesn't work. 2. This triple backslash in  `"C:\\\abcd.txt"`  is fishy anyway.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: not just "fishy" – it should not work at all. The character combination `\a` gets interpreted since C99: "The alert sequence (`'\a'`) was added by popular demand to replace, for instance, the ASCII BEL code explicitly coded as `'\007'`". Flatly contradicting this, OP states it *does* work for the root folder.

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, I know, that's why I wrote "fishy" and why I requested the exact code for both cases.

Comment: As per @MichaelWalz observation, the proper syntax should be with only a double backslash (the backslash to escape the backslash, resulting in a single backslash in the string, the `a` not being further translated)

Comment: For a test, he could try to remove a file `bcd.txt`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: the example is badly formatted which may or may not be part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you have one too many backslashes.

the first backslash escapes the following backslash so there is a backslash in the string. The second backslash, followed by `a` is an escape sequence to insert the bell character `\007` in the string. So you now want to delete file `C:\<bell>cde.txt`, which clearly doesn't exist.

use:

```
if (remove("C:\\abcd.txt") == -1)
```

Comment: OK  I know that /// but I can only delete the text files in c drive in single word folder... For example I can delete c:\\tmp\\abcd.txt and delete c:\\programme files\\abcd.txt

Comment: You _can_ delete them or you _can't_ delete them?

Comment: Ops sorry my bad, I can't delete  c:\\programme files\\abcd.txt

Comment: Try first `access`. It will tell you f the file exists, e.g. `if (access(filename))==0)`